# How can I create and use multiple arrays of 100 elements at a specific address in memory in MIPS Assembly? (QTSpim)

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, qtspim

So on this site, I've learned that you can create arrays at a specific address in memory using QTSpim's data segment like so:

```
.data 0xA000
A: .word 3:40

.data 0xB000
B: .word 4:40

.data 0xC000
C: .word 0:40
```

(This creating arrays of elements with a specific starting memory address.)
However when I try to run this through a simple multiplication and subtraction calculation, I keep running into a lot of exceptions, most likely to do with my referencing of words in the array.

[CPU EXCEPTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOtWl.png)

[BAD ADDRESS EXCEPTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjY3V.png)

Can someone tell me how I should properly reference words in these arrays?

Currently, my code is this:

```
.text
.globl main

main:
    la $a1,A          #Needs to load the address of arrayA into $a1
    la $a2,B          #Needs to load the address of arrayB into $a2
    la $a3,C          #Needs to load the address of arrayC into $a3
    li $t0,0          #Declare counter variable (i)

loop:
    lw $t2,0($a1)        #Needs to load the value of the arrayA at the counter offset into t2
    lw $t3,8($a2)        #Needs to load the value of the arrayB 8 bits after the counter offset into t3

    mul $t4,$t2,$t3     #Multiply A[i] and B[i+2]

    sw $t4,0($a3)       #Save result of all calculations into C[i]

    li $v0,1            #Print the value in the C[i]
    lw $a0,0($a3)
    syscall

    li $v0, 4           #print newline
    la $a0, newline
    syscall

    addi $a1,$a1,4      #Increase all address offsets by 1 word or 4 bits
    addi $a2,$a2,4
    addi $a3,$a3,4
    addi $t0,$t0,1      #Increase counter variable by 1
    beq $t0,20,exit     #If the counter variable (i) < 98, exit
    j loop


    exit:
        li $v0, 10  #exit syscall
        syscall

.data 0xA000
A: .word 3:40

.data 0xB000
B: .word 4:40

.data 0xC000
C: .word 0:40
newline: .asciiz " \n"
```

In a high level language like C this is supposed to look a little like:

```
int A[40], B[40], C[40];
for (i=0; i < 20; i++) {
       C[i] = A[i] * B[i+2];
       cout << C[i] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Verify your syntax of `3:40` is actually correct. Note the exception complains about address `0xA004` so your data at `0xA000` has apparently been accessed correctly so you have done something right.

Comment: You are placing your arrays in a memory area that is marked as "reserved", and is not available for your use.

Comment: Thank you very much @jasonharper , I changed the address location to 0x1000A000...etc and it worked!